# StringExpression: pattern reapeted one or more times matches pattern repeated zero times

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I try to construct patterns using Riffle and Except

```
StringExpression@Riffle[{"a", "b", "c"}, Except[{"=", ","}] ..]
```

and expect it to match "a_b_c", but not "a_bc" because Except is repeated .. one or more times.

However,

```
StringMatchQ["a_bc", StringExpression@Riffle[{"a", "b", "c"}, Except[{"=", ","}] ..]]
```

returns True. Could anyone explain why is it so?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but I think this has something to do with how the pattern is translated into a Perl-compatible regular expression and then understood by the PCRE library. The regex is given by `First@StringPattern\`PatternConvert@Riffle[{"a", "b", "c"}, Except[{"=", ","}] ..]` and comes out as `(?ms)(?:a|(?:[^=,])+|b|(?:[^=,])+|c)`. Perhaps someone with more experience of using regular expressions will be able to suggest why this behaves as it does.

Comment: `StringExpression@@`...

Comment: @rasher, thank you for the answer. OleksandrR., thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're invoking when you should be applying:

```
StringExpression@Riffle[{"a", "b", "c"}, Except[{"=", ","}] ..]

(* StringExpression[{"a", Except[{"=", ","}] .., "b",  Except[{"=", ","}] .., "c"}] *)
```

VS

```
StringExpression @@ Riffle[{"a", "b", "c"}, Except[{"=", ","}] ..]

(* "a" ~~ Except[{"=", ","}] .. ~~ "b" ~~ Except[{"=", ","}] .. ~~ "c" *)
```

Note that the first way ends up equivalent to

```
StringMatchQ[...,{"a", Except[{"=", ","}] .., "b", Except[{"=", ","}] .., "c"}]
```

which of course gives you unwanted matches (recall that the list is treated as alternatives).

Using application, the correct

```
StringMatchQ[...,"a" ~~ Except[{"=", ","}] .. ~~ "b" ~~ Except[{"=", ","}] .. ~~ "c"]
```

is generated, giving the desired results.

Comment: (+1) Didn't know that `StringMatchQ` accepts list as a second argument. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: It must be... but I'll be damned if I can find it. I've been using that form for ages... `StringCases` has that form documented, perhaps one of those "...I wonder if this works here...", it did, and I've used it since.